# Continuous loop through an array to create horizontal ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to create a horizontal ticker using this existing js so that my array ticker will have the same animation and functionality as the other single-line news ticker on my page.

Currently my js turns my 3 li's into an array, but then lumps them together and scrolls them across the width of the ticker as one block.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var block_text = $('.ticker li').map(function() { return $(this).html();}).toArray();
  $(".ticker").html("<p>" + block_text + "</p>");
  var ticker_text = $('.ticker p');
  var ticker_width = $(".ticker").width();
  var text_x = ticker_width;

  scroll_ticker = function() {
    text_x--;
    ticker_text.css("left", text_x);
    if (text_x < -1 * ticker_text.width()) {
      text_x = ticker_width;
    }
  }
  setInterval(scroll_ticker, 10);
});
```

```css
#iFeatures {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
  height: 73px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 126px;
  background-color: rgba(0,39,62,.85);
}
.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ticker p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
}

.ticker a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iFeatures">
    <div class="ticker">
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 1.</a></li>
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 2.</a></li>
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 3.</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/9va9r3n4/1/

What I would like to do is continuously loop through this array and animate each li the same way that the original block was being animated. This is my attempt at creating a for loop to do this, but it isn't working.

```js
var myStringArray = $('.ticker li').map(function() { return $(this).html();}).toArray();
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var ticker_width = $(".ticker").width();

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(myStringArray[i]);
    
    //Do something
    scroll_ticker = function() {
        ticker_width--;
        i.css("left", ticker_width);
    }
    setInterval(scroll_ticker, 10);
    
}
```

```css
#iFeatures {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
  height: 73px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 126px;
  background-color: rgba(0,39,62,.85);
}
.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ticker p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
}

.ticker a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iFeatures">
    <div class="ticker">
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 1.</a></li>
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 2.</a></li>
        <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 3.</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Work in progress demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/9va9r3n4/

Open to any and all suggestions that might help me accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do. First I kept the **`li`** items in the array, not just their text. Then when one item passed through the **`ticker`**, I looped in the array and changed the contents of the ticker to the next item in the array. This way every time each item will pass through the screen and then loop back from the begining.

**Keep the element not the text:**

```
var block_arr = $('.ticker li a p').map(function() { return $(this).get(0);}).toArray()
```

**Loop through the array and change contents of ticker:**

```
ticker_item = $(block_arr[
              (block_arr.indexOf(ticker_item.get(0)) + 1 == block_arr.length) ?
              0 :
              block_arr.indexOf(ticker_item.get(0)) + 1]);

$(".ticker").html(ticker_item);
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ob70vh3d/).

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Try utilizing `.queue()` to loop through , animate each `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cycles = 0;
    var ticker = $(".ticker");
    var items = ticker.find("li").css({
            "list-style": "none",
            "position": "relative"
    });
    items.hide();
    var _ticker = function () {
        return ticker.queue("ticker", $.map(items, function (el, i) {
            return function (next) {
                $(el).css("left", ticker.width())
                    .show()
                    .animate({
                    left: "-" + (ticker.width() - $(el).width() / 2)
                }, 3000 // adjust `duration` of `el`:`li` "tick" here
                 , "linear", function () {
                    $(this).hide(0, next)
                })
            }
        })).dequeue("ticker").promise("ticker")
    };
    (function cycle() {
      _ticker().then(function (el) {
        // do stuff when all `li` within `ticker` have completed animations,
        // increment `cycles` , log cycles completed, 
        // call `cycle()` for infinite loop of `_ticker()`      
        ++cycles;
        console.log(cycles + " `_ticker` cycles completed", el);
        cycle()
      })
    }())
});
```

```css
#iFeatures {
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
  height: 73px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 126px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 39, 62, .85);
}
.ticker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ticker p {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
}
.ticker a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iFeatures">
  <div class="ticker">
    <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 1.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 2.</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="##">This is a test ticker 3.</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9va9r3n4/4/

Comment: If you read the question carefully, although it is long, it doesn't say anywhere to have a vertical scroll. It says `continuously loop through this array and animate each li the same way that the original block was being animated`. You didn't even read the question!

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Yes, you are correct. Read question. Not certain why , how "vertical" got interpreted , here. Thanks for providing "downvote" reason , description !

Comment: @RaeenHashemi Must have been experiencing "vertigo" earlier :) Cheers